# How i can restoremy database psql heroku to other server?

Tags: node.js, database, github, heroku, psql

How i can backup data my database psql on Heroku to my local computer and i want to move to another sever. can heroku backup a database my server to my local computer?

Comment: Are you able to connect to the postgress directly from your laptop?

Comment: no, so i use a github for fork to another github account, and i use a heroku to deploy to my github. And i want move to another server, from heroku to another server. And i need Database psqll for a restore my database from Heroku to a new server.

Comment: github is for the code, not for the database. Did you configure the postgress addon in the heroku web console? Do you have access to the host, port, user and password?

Comment: I make a web TeleDrive From Heroku with Telegram API. https://youtu.be/Vwcx_cXEttM this how i make a website. iam sorry I don't understand waht you say. I'm still a beginner

Comment: And after make that, i want move to another server (not heroku server), And i ask to community how to move to another server, and there say need a databse psql for move to another server. And i don't understand how to find or how to create a database psql for me to download. And move to another Server (not Heroku)

Answer (score 0):

If you app needs some sql database, you should have access to the connection parameters like the url, user and password. There is no chance for you app to connect to a sql database without these parameters

Reviewing the [teledrive docs](https://teledriveapp.com/docs/Installation/manual/), I found the variable which contains that values:

- DATABASE_URL
- format: postgresql://[user]:[password]@[host]:[port][/dbname][?paramspec]

Is similar to java and other languages: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/connecting-to-relational-databases-on-heroku-with-java#using-the-jdbc_database_url-in-a-spring-boot-app

You can get these values usually in the [environment variables configuration](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars#using-the-heroku-dashboard) in heroku

Something like this:

[image]

Your duty is to find these values.

### import & export using some IDE

If you have the database connection parameters and the database has public access, you could use any database ide . I recommend you the dbeaver because is free and powerful. You could use it to connect to any database in the galaxy.

Here are the steps to export and restore a database.

https://community.pyramidanalytics.com/t/h7hk07w/how-to-backup-and-restore-a-postgresql-database-via-dbeaver

Basically you should:

- connect to your heroku postgress,
- export the data
- connect to another postgres
- import the data

### import & export using the shell

This is more fast than an IDE. Check this to understand it: https://simplebackups.com/blog/postgresql-pgdump-and-pgrestore-guide-examples/